# Android Facebook dialog appears with cropped title text

Tags: android, facebook

I have followed the Android SDK sample and integrated the code as per instructions and it is working fine. But in some devices the title at top of dialog is cropped. This problem is happening in Motorola Milestone, Android Firmware version 2.1 update1. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I work at Facebook and this might potentially be a bug.  Is this native SSO auth dialog or the webview popup dialog?

There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/203) pending on our github repo regarding the webview popup dialog and when the keyboard is displayed.  It might be the same issue you're describing here.  I would try merging his commit into your local copy of your Facebook Android SDK and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: the fbdialog update taken from given github repo isn't solve my problem.This update solved the keypad issue only.I have used webview dialog only.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I would advise opening a bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs with all the details so we can take a look at this.